# How to use va_arg to modify the value of a variadic parameter

Tags: c++, variadic-functions

```
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void tag_log(const char *format, ...) {
    va_list ap;
    va_start(ap, format);
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        va_arg(ap, int) += 100; // is wrong?
    }
    va_end(ap);
    va_start(ap, format);
    vprintf(format, ap);
    va_end(ap);
}

int main() {
    tag_log("%d, %d, %d, %d\n", 1, 2, 3, 4);
}
```

Since va_arg returns an rvalue, the content cannot be modified. How to modify the content of the variable parameter?

Expected output: 101, 102, 103, 104

thanks!!!

Comment: `= 100;` would assign `100` not increment by `100`

Comment: I'm pretty sure there's no way to do what you're trying to do.

Comment: @SteveSummit But it is theoretically possible

Comment: I guess it depends on what you mean by "theoretically possible"! :-)  I mean, it's equally theoretically possible that `int i = 1000000000000000000000000000000000000000; printf("%d\n", i+1);` could print `1000000000000000000000000000000000000001`.  I see what you're trying to do, I've written (nonportable) code that does what you're trying to do, but I'm afraid it's never going to be possible in C.

Comment: @SteveSummit 
I just need to get the address of this parameter in the stack, and then assign it. And your example is a 32-bit integer overflow

Comment: @QuanfaFu It's theoretically possible for my example to work — on a machine with 130-bit ints. :-)  But, when it comes to what you're trying to do, the problem is that *not all arguments are necessarily passed on the stack*.  Some arguments may be passed in registers.  (Less likely for varargs functions, perhaps, but not impossible.)  So `va_arg` has to be smart enough to fetch out of a register, if necessary, but it's unlikely that a `va_arg` implementation would be written to be able to store into a register, since there's no requirement for it to.  Theoretically it could, but not likely.

Comment: @QuanfaFu Please do not change the question in such a way that existing answers becomes useless. Ask a new question if you want to know how it's done in C

Comment: @TedLyngmo In fairness (or perhaps I just have too soft a spot for newbies), from the point of view of the OP, there was no change to the question.  OP wanted an answer for C, mistakenly additionally tagged with C++, and is now trying to correct that mistake.  I understand your frustration, I do — I've lost track of the number of my careful answers I've had to delete, or that have been deleted against my will, under similar circumstances — but it's a risk you take when you answer here.  Me, I'd leave your answer in any case, as it's not "useless".

Comment: You should not use variadic arguments form C in C++ code. Templates are more flexible, type safe and faster. Note there is `fmt` library which was incorporated into C++20 standard.

Comment: @MarekR The OP is not coding in C++.  The question is mistagged.

Comment: @SteveSummit Now I see that comment under answer specifies that this is C.

Answer (score 4):

> `va_arg(ap, int) = 100; // is wrong?`

Yes, it's wrong. `va_arg` returns an rvalue (which isn't assignable).

I suggest making a variadic template instead.

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <utility>

template<class... Args>
void tag_log(const char *format, Args&&... args) {
    ((args += 100), ...); // fold expression
    std::printf(format, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}

int main() {
    tag_log("%d, %d, %d, %d\n", 1, 2, 3, 4);
}
```

Output:

```
101, 102, 103, 104
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.
May I ask if there is a way in C, I am not using C++

Comment: @Quanfa I've edited the tags on your question so that they include `C` and no longer include `C++`.

Comment: Sorry, but the compilation cannot pass, because the utility header file is in C++, can we not use the variadic parameter template? thanks!!!

Comment: @QuanfaFu Normally I would suggest that you change the language tag in the question to the correct language but since you've now actually gotten an answer for C++ (which is what you asked for) I instead suggest that you ask a new question and tag it with [tag:c] instead.

Comment: @JohnFilleau I would probably have changed the tag myself if there wasn't already an existing answer but since there now is one, I think it's better to leave the tag alone.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Sorry, i change the language tag

Comment: @QuanfaFu Please don't - it makes existing answers useless. Ask a new question instead if you want to know how it's done in C.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I don't disagree with your reasoning, but since both the OP and John Filleau have expressed the opinion that the original intent should stand, I hope there won't be an edit war over this.

Comment: @SteveSummit I'm done :-) If OP decides to change the tag, I'll back down and delete my answer